# The rank of general inverse of $A$ times $A$?

Tags: matrices, inverse

Supposing $X$ is the general inverse of $A$, that $AXA = A$. 
Then $XA$ is idempotent, that is $(XA)(XA) = XA$.

Why is the rank of $XA$ equal to the rank of $A$ ?

Thanks.

Comment: Think about the determinant of $A$, you know that $A$ is invertible and has an inverse. What does that say about $XA$?

Comment: @mark Thanks ! But I think A doesn't need to be invertible since we are considering the "general inverse" so that in this case A can be m by n?

Comment: How is *the* general inverse defined? Because $AXA=A$ only implies that the rank of $X$ is *at least* the rank of $A$.

Comment: @SoManyProb_for_a_broken_heart. My apologies, I did not see general inverse.

Comment: The property $AXA=A$ does not uniquely define $X$ when $A$ is not invertible. Perhaps you mean the Moore-Penrose Psuedoinverse, which satisfies $AXA=A, XAX=X, (AX)^t=AX$ and $(XA)^t=XA$?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On the one hand $\text{rank}(XA)\leq \min\left(\text{rank}(X), \text{rank}(A)\right)\leq \text{rank}(A)$.

On the other hand $\text{rank}(A)=\text{rank}(AXA)\leq \min\left(\text{rank}(A), \text{rank}(XA)\right)\leq \text{rank}(XA)$.

Comment: thanks! that's very clean and nice !